# Rails validates_uniqueness_of with a :conditions param

Tags: ruby-on-rails

`validates_uniqueness_of :prod_id, :scope => [:col_id, :parent_col_id], :conditions => lambda { |table| table[:state].not_in(%w(cancelled denied)) }`

I can't find any documentation for passing :conditions to validates_uniqueness_of... I'm looking for an explanation.

Update - thanks for the answer, a custom validation or using if or less would make sense... however this is pre-existing code that I'm trying to fully understand before changing.

Comment: Might have to make your own validation method.

Answer (score 4):

You can make your own validation method for this. For example:

```
validates_uniqueness_of :prod_id, :scope => [:col_id, :parent_col_id],
                                  :if => :custom_validation

def custom_validation
  #your code here
end
```

Comment: Thanks, I've updated my question to clarify that I'm after an explanation of pre-existing code.